# Combine INT, TIME fields and compute Elapsed Percentage

Tags: type-conversion, cast, computed-column

Need calculation and conversion help...

Columns:
[Days] INT
[hh:mm:ss] Time
[AllowedRuntimeMinutes] INT

Need to combine [Days]+[hh:mm:ss] as the duration the query has been running, and then calculate the elapsed percentage over the allowed run time.

So possibly some form of ([Days]+[hh:mm:ss] as Duration)-AllowedRuntimeMinutes/AllowedRunTimeMinutes*100  ?

Comment: Thanks to ICHP on Reddit for suggesting I convert all values to seconds with a decimal point, then calculate the ratio. This is what I came up with, but I am still tweaking it not to round the percentage as much:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FORMAT(((CONCAT(CONVERT(INT,L.[Days]/ 60) + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,L.[DAYS] % 60),2), CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,0), DATEDIFF(MS, DATEADD(S,0,0), L.[hh:mm:ss])/1000.0)))-RL.[AllowedRuntimeMinutes])/RL.[AllowedRuntimeMinutes]/60,'P') AS [ExceededPercentage]

Comment: If this works (it's not very legible as a comment), you should answer your own question! But why store days as `INT`s? You should be using `TIMESTAMP(TZ)`s instead!